# How To Embed Videos From A YouTube Channel with Title?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I found a piece of code in jQuery to retrieve last videos automatically from my YouTube channel. But the problem is that code doesn't show titles of videos. I want to show video title under player on my website.

What should I change in order to show videos with titles?

Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<iframe class="latestVideoEmbed" vnum='0' cid="UC7WnrV5aBx7LjWp0lorB73Q" </iframe>
```

JavaScript:

```
var reqURL = "https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json?rss_url=" + encodeURIComponent("https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=");

function loadVideo(iframe) {
  $.getJSON(reqURL + iframe.getAttribute('cid'),
    function(data) {
      var videoNumber = (iframe.getAttribute('vnum') ? Number(iframe.getAttribute('vnum')) : 0);
      console.log(videoNumber);
      var link = data.items[videoNumber].link;
      id = link.substr(link.indexOf("=") + 1);
      iframe.setAttribute("src", "https://youtube.com/embed/" + id + "?controls=0&autoplay=1");
    }
  );
}

var iframes = document.getElementsByClassName('latestVideoEmbed');
for (var i = 0, len = iframes.length; i < len; i++) {
  loadVideo(iframes[i]);
}
```

jQuery link:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Did you try to print result after fetching a data from youtube server

Comment: No, I didn't. I will try :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long suffering I myself solved the issue. I have added some codes. HTML is same. Here is the code:

```
function loadVideo(iframe) {
  $.getJSON(reqURL + iframe.getAttribute('cid'),
    function(data) {
      var videoNumber = (iframe.getAttribute('vnum') ? Number(iframe.getAttribute('vnum')) : 0);
      console.log(videoNumber);
      var link = data.items[videoNumber].link;
      id = link.substr(link.indexOf("=") + 1);
      iframe.setAttribute("src", "https://youtube.com/embed/" + id + "?controls=0&autoplay=1");

      var url = 'https://www.youtube.com/channel/' + channelID;
      $.getJSON('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=' + id + '&key=' + apiKey + '&fields=items(snippet(title))&part=snippet', {format: 'json', url: url}, function (data) {
        var h2s = $("h2")
        console.log(data.items)
        $(h2s[videoNumber]).html(data.items[0].snippet.title)

      });
    }
  );
}
```